# Should I use the simple past or past perfect in the following passages?

Tags: tense

> My rabbit was probably bitten by a snake. A good theory; however, just because **I saw/had seen** one today didn't
>   mean he was bitten by one in his last hours.
>
> As far as I could remember, my dog had never chased any birds. He
>   **was/had been** only interested in cats.

This is past-tense narrative talking about past events. I'm a little confused about what tense to use in the **bolded** parts.

Maybe I'm mixing up things? Should I use the simple past or part perfect in the sentences above?

Comment: Is there any connection between those sentences?

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, they are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Ought to be "***bitten*** by a snake".  In the first fragment it is unclear who is "he" and why you used "did".  Did *what*?  Did *be bitten*?

Comment: @VictorBazarov I edited the sentence to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both passages the choice gives a slight difference in meaning.

Let's imagine the time at which you discover the rabbit dead.  You **have seen** a snake (it was *some time before*, doesn't matter when, just matters there was *at some point* a snake around).  You make a conjecture that it *may or may not have been* the cause of the rabbit's demise.  Moving to the past tense shifts everything, including "**have seen**" -> "**had seen**".

Now, if you wan to say that the moment you *lay your eyes* on the snake was "**today**", in other words at a **particular time**, it also works.  It's the *proximity in time* between *seeing the snake* and the *rabbit's death* what you're conveying.  So, past tense "I **saw** one today" also works.

In the second passage (about the dog), if brought to the present time, you can say "he **is** only interested in cats", which simply characterizes the dog's behavior in general.  Or, you can say "he **has been** only interested in cats" (expressing thus the behavior patterns you observed *frequently in the past*).  That's the difference.

Both are grammatically OK.

Comment: Thanks. So, if the dog was already dead (past-tense narration), I can only use "had been"? Since "was" would imply that the dog is still alive at the time of the narration?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so.  It wasn't clear from the passage that the dog was dead.